# Array map method couldn't accept potentially undefined parameter

Tags: typescript

I am trying to find the latest date in a list of dates returned from an API call:

```js
const latest = Math.max(...testList.map(test => test.endedAt?.getTime()));
```

But `testList` which is of type `TestList`, which extends `Array<TestRun>` :

```js
export declare class TestRunList extends Array<TestRun> {
    constructor(param: Array<TestRun> | number);
    static fromJson(data: Array<any>): TestRunList;
    static toJson(data: TestRunList): Array<any>;
};

export declare class TestRun {
    ....
    readonly endedAt?: Date;

};
```

As such, I'm getting a compiler error that says:

```
Argument of type 'number | undefined' is not assignable to parameter of type 'number'.
  Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'number'.
```

What's the right way to resolve this error?

Comment: A fast solution would be to add a logical or in the map that returns 0 (or any other number, maybe -1 if that fits better) if endedAt does not exist `test.endedAt?.getTime() || 0`. That way you would get rid of the undefined.

Comment: It would be better to use null-coalescing operator, so as not to interfere with the potentially valid 0 return of `getTime`.  So `test.endedAt?.getTime() ?? valueInsteadOfUndefined`.

Answer (score 0):

Using [optional chaining](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining) results in `undefined` for any *nullish* chain participants.

The Typescript definition for `Math.max()` is

```ts
max(...values: number[]): number;
```

so `undefined` is not a valid argument type.

You should default to a relevant *earliest* value when `endedAt` is not defined using the [nullish coalescing operator (`??`)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Nullish_coalescing_operator). For example

```ts
const defaultTime = Number.NEGATIVE_INFINITY;

const latest = Math.max(
  ...testList.map((test) => test.endedAt?.getTime() ?? defaultTime)
);
```

You could also use `0` as a default but that could lead to false positives if all your dates are pre `1970-01-01`.

Comment: Thanks! I used this but got an error that says `Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: _a.getTime is not a function` and looking at code executed in browser, this line got translated to `var latest = Math.max.apply(Math, testRunList.map(function (testRun) { var _a, _b; return (_b = (_a = testRun.endedAt) === null || _a === void 0 ? void 0 : _a.getTime()) !== null && _b !== void 0 ? _b : defaultTime; }));`, do you know why this is?